# Segment variable default values are not assigned as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have the following routing in RouteConfig.cs:

```
    routes.MapRoute(name: "",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/InwDocSource{id}",
        defaults: new { Controller = "InwardDocument", action = "AddDocument", id = "1" });
```

And in my controller :

```
   public class InwardDocumentController : Controller     
     public ActionResult AddDcument(string id){
       if(id=="1")
         ViewBag.IdInWords="The received id is ONE";
       else if(id=="2")
         ViewBag.IdInWords="The received id is TWO";
       else
         ViewBag.IdInWords="The received id is SOMETHING ELSE";
       return View("Index");// FYI the Index.cshtml is not strongly typed
     }
   }
```

So the above mapping will match any url with 3 segments, third of which should begin with "InwDocSource". And all the segment variables have their default values in case they're not passed from the browser. Lets assume that my root web site is www.mysite.net and the above url mapping is the only one in the RouteConfig.cs file

1. How come when I type just www.mysite.com the URL matches the pattern and I get "The received id is ONE"? I know that all the variables are defaulted to some values but the mapping says that the third segment must begin with InwDocSource.
2. The second is weirder though: If I enter www.mysite.com/InwardDocument/AddDocument/InwDocSource 
   I get "The received id is SOMETHING ELSE", so the default value of 1 does not get assigned to the third segment variable. Why's that?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question, in the second case I get "The received id is SOMETHING ELSE".

Comment: `{controller}/{action}/InwDocSource{id}` with your parameters becomes `/InwardDocument/AddDocument/InwDocSource1` so `string id` is "InwDocSource1" (not "1")

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I think this code proves you wrong:

When I say 

ViewBag=string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/{3}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, RouteData.Values["controller"], RouteData.Values["action"], RouteData.Values["id"]);

 I get  www.mysite.com/InwardDocument/AddDocument/1   so, string id is not "InwDocSource1" but just "1"

Comment: Interesting, just cut and pasted your code into my project (corrected spelling - AddDcument -> AddDocument) and entered ..InwardDocument/AddDocument/InwDocSource and I get the value of id = "InwDocSourc"

Comment: Is this (from your code above) `url: "{controller}/{action}/InwDocSource{id}"` just a typo? (no forward slash between InwDocSource and {id})

Comment: You're right, that way you get "InwDocSource".(Which is still strange). And if you omit the third or all of the segments, this time you'll get "1". So my question cover all this concerns

Comment: No, that's not a typo. That's the way you say that there are three segments, all segments are variable (means they are not static) and that the third segment begins with some static text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55301/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mike-jm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll begin to answer in the reverse order

1. The route mapping says that it's going to match a url with 3 segments third of which must begin with `InwDocSource`. So when I pass `www.mysite.com/InwardDocument/AddDocument/InwDocSource` there are 3 segments and the third one does indeed begin with the static string `InwDocSource`, it does not have to continue or end with something else. :) So the value for the third segment becomes `InwDocSource` and that's why I get `The received id is SOMETHING ELSE`
2. When I pass just the domain part the routing configuration will still match the above mapping, because all three segments have their default values in case  any of them are not passed explicitly.